# What is the difference between include and block in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to make a bootstrap theme for [PhileCMS](http://philecms.com) which uses Twig. Right now I'm working on the menu. I've been searching to find out how to make a page active, and I've been seeing stuff about blocks. Right now my index.html looks something like this

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
<body>
{% include 'nav.html' %}
<div class="container"}
{{ content }}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

My nav.html looks something like this:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation"><a class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'home' %}active{% endif %}">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'about' %}active{% endif %}">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'contact' %}active{% endif %}">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h3 class="text-muted">{{ site_title }}</h3>
</div>
```

Is this proper coding practice, or should I be doing something with  blocks? I don't really understand how blocks work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include whole new template with new blocks. - That is what include do. You inject a template or piece of template defined in other file. So:

```
{% include 'nav.html' %}
```

will inject whatever you have put there and it will replace this whole phrase, this line of code with content of nav.html.

On the other hand when you use {% block body %} for example you override this body block which is inherited from parent template. For example:

If you have block named body in base.html.twig and you will inherit from it like this in another template(let's say blog.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

and then do this:

```
{% block body %}
   Hello World
{% endblock %}
```

You will put this hello world inside of body block in base.html.twig.

I hope it's now clear to you.

P.S

If you want to use twig make sure you use twig extension!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mostly makes sense. Is it good form to use import within a block?

Comment: Also, when does one use .twig vs .html?

Comment: Let me answer second question first: It's just extension so always - if you want to use twig and its functions you have to use *.twig extension and yes it's ok to do import thing inside a block. For example you could create a template for displaying errors on website and just import it wherever you want to display them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for best-practices, then as mentioned in the Symfony's Templating documentation:

> When building your application, you may choose to follow this method or simply make each page template extend the base application template directly (e.g. {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}). **The three-template model** is a best-practice method used by vendor bundles so that the base template for a bundle can be easily overridden to properly extend your application's base layout.

The idea behind this is to have:

1- a **base template** (level 1)

2-A **layout template** (level 2)

3-An **individual template** (level 3)

Here is a sample code that illustrates this (originally from the Symfony2) [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating/inheritance.html)

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Blog Application</h1>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}


{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for entry in blog_entries %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**p.s**: Even tough you wouldn't be dealing with Symfony2, but IMHO the principle should be the same, since we are using the Twig templating engine.